# Optimizer keeps almost the initial values

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to get used to torch, and after optimizing a simple example (x^2+y^2), I tried something different.

This should optimize a path in a [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) metric. I give as input a set of points, and it should move them upwards to create a curved shape. The code is as follows.

First I define the correct distance:

```
import numpy
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import pandas

# poincare distance between two points
def poincare_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2, R=1):
  r = torch.sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2)
  matg = torch.diag(torch.tensor([2.0, 2.0])) * (4 * R**4/(R**2-r**2)**2)
  delta = torch.tensor( [[x2 - x1], [y2 - y1]] )
  f = torch.sqrt( delta.T @ matg @ delta )
  return f
```

The loss function uses two Lagrange multipliers. I'd like the points to keep an even distance between them, and the first and last points should remain the same:

```
# loss function: arc length + equidistance between all points + equality 
# between the fist and last point and the original (should remain the same)
def poincare_loss(coords, k, kequality, eqfirst, eqlast):
    res = torch.zeros( (coords.shape[0]-1) )
    for i in range(0, coords.shape[0]-1):
        res[i] = poincare_distance(coords[i  ][0], coords[i  ][1],
                                   coords[i+1][0], coords[i+1][1])
    
    diffs = torch.zeros( (res.shape[0]-1) )
    for i in range(0, res.shape[0]-1):
        diffs[i] = res[i] - res[i+1]

    eq = kequality * (torch.sum((coords[0] - eqfirst)**2) + torch.sum((coords[-1] - eqlast)**2))

    d = torch.sum(res) + k * torch.sum(diffs**2) + eq
    return d
```

Next I read the input file, a set of initial points with the same y-coordinate:

```
# handy
usedevice = 'cpu'
usedtype = torch.float32

# load the file in one float per line: x x x x ... y y y y y y
arc_csv = pandas.read_csv("../mesh/poincare/arc.txt", header=None, delimiter=' ')
arc = torch.tensor(arc_csv.values.astype(numpy.float64), dtype=usedtype, device=usedevice)

# coordinates as tensor [ [x,y], [x,y], ... ]
coords = arc.reshape([2,40]).T
```

After, I can start the loop. I create the initial coordinates to be optimized `inicoords`, and the Lagrange multipliers `k` and `keq`:

```
# initial guess
inicoords = coords.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)

# lagrange multipliers for the equidistance, and equality of first and last point
k = torch.tensor([100.0], dtype=usedtype, device=usedevice, requires_grad=True)
keq = torch.tensor([1000.0], dtype=usedtype, device=usedevice, requires_grad=True)

# optimizer
learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = optim.Adam([inicoords, k, keq], lr=learning_rate)

num_steps = 1000

for step in range(num_steps):
    optimizer.zero_grad()  
    loss = poincare_loss(inicoords, k, keq, coords[0], coords[-1])    
    # print("step", step, "loss", loss)     
    loss.backward()        
    optimizer.step()

optimal_inicoords = inicoords.detach().numpy()
optimal_k = k.detach().numpy()
optimal_keq = keq.detach().numpy()
optimal_value = poincare_loss(inicoords, k, keq, coords[0], coords[-1]).item()

print("Optimal coords:\n", optimal_inicoords)
print("Optimal k:\n", optimal_k)
print("Optimal keq:\n", optimal_keq)
print("Optimal Value:\n", optimal_value)

print("FIRST:\n", optimal_inicoords[0])
print("LAST:\n", optimal_inicoords[-1])
```

The problem is that, even playing with `k` and `keq`, and with the learning rate, the points almost remain the initial ones. They vary a little, but they almost the same.

The y coordinate is almost identical, and the multipliers `k` and `keq` are identical.

Being a newcomer to torch, I am really thinking I might have misunderstood how a torch optimizer works.

Any hints are more than welcome...

Comment: I suggest not to declare a new zero-filled tensor in your `poincare_loss` function, it prevents gradient computation. Use concatenation or stacking operation instead. (FYI, I didn't read your post from start to end so maybe another problem is the reason)

Comment: @Hayoung you nailed it! I implemented the loss function without creating new vectors with `torch::zeros` it works! If you can create an answer I will mark it. Thank you very much!